# Alguien sabe por qué no responde mi archivo .ipynb en vs code?

Tags: python, vscode, jupyter

He estado trabajando normalmente en mi VScode y cuando voy a trbajar en un archivo ipynb me aparece lo siguiente, alguien puede ayudarme con esto? por favor [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]